# Как запускать Browser sync в один щелчок

Tags: browsersync

Существует ли способ запустить браузер синк в одно касание,не вводя в powershell каждый раз browser-sync start --server --files "*.html, css/*.css" ?

Comment: Много способов. **1.** Использовать плагин для Browsersync в Вашей IDE, например,такой есть в Sublime Text, **2.** Запустить плагин для Browsersync в Вашем сборщике, как то Grunt, **3.** Создать .bat-файл, куда вписать Вашу команду `browser-sync start --server --files ".html, css/.css"` и запустить этот файл шорткатом, например, через [**nnCron**](http://www.nncron.ru/), **4.** Пользоваться ConEmu в Far mode, а не Powershell. ConEmu запоминает ранее введённые Вами команды. Как Вы начинаете писать `bro`, ConEmu предложит выбрать вариант, который Вы уже когда-то вводили. Спасибо.

Comment: https://youtu.be/j50zjiu_-8U - БЫСТРЫЙ способ АВТООБНОВЛЕНИЯ странички, при написании кода html css js, чекайте)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Windows есть следующий способ:

1. создаёшь файл с расширением bat;
2. кладёшь его в директорию с файлами, которые нужно отслеживать;
3. в него прописываешь `start "" browser-sync start -s -f "*.html, css/*.css"`

После чего жмёшь на файл - и всё работает.

Если хочешь, чтобы у тебя bat файл запускался, скажем, с рабочего стола, то нужно будет добавить перед вышеуказанной командой путь к папке с нужными файлами:

```
cd C:\Users\User\...
start "" browser-sync ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь reloader.bat и туда помещаешь:

```
if "%~1" == "" (start "" /min "%comspec%" /c "%~f0" any_word & exit /b)
cd %cd%
browser-sync start --server --files «css/*.css, js/*.js, *.html»
```

Только поправь пути к файлам  под свой проект, если они нестандартные.

```
«папка_css/.css, папка_js/.js, *.html»
```

Кидаешь в корень проекта и запускаешь без каких-либо доп манипуляций.
Файл запускается в свернутом виде. Место запуска определяется автоматом. И запускается browsersync.